# Keep Control's default property from being included into Design-time serialisation

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, resx

I have UserControl, created half in VS Designer and half in code.
I want to create new instance of this UserControl from code, but set some of its default properties to different values every time.
Example (edit w real code):

```
// in my Main Form..
var newFrame = new RPictureFrame(); // my UserControl
newFrame.Width = 50;
newFrame.Height = 50;
newFrame.Location = new Point(0,0);
this.Controls.Add(newFrame);

newFrame = new RPictureFrame();
newFrame.Width = 200;
newFrame.Height = 400;
newFrame.Location = new Point(0,150);
this.Controls.Add(newFrame);
```

Original **wrong** example:

```
var newMyUserControl1 = new MyUserControl();  
newMyUserControl1.size.Width = 50;  

var newMyUserControl2 = new MyUserControl();  
newMyUserControl2.size.Width = 200;
```

What sometimes happen though is the new value set by me right after creating the new instance of control seem to get ignored.
My only explanation is, that since my UserControl is designed in Designer, all its default properties are in fact kept serialised in .resx file (?). When I create new instance in runtime, a deserialisation is started in separate thread (I have no control of). When I set some of the properties accidentaly before they get deserialised, my value gets overwriten by the ser'd value right after.
I didn't find any info about how the creation of Designer-created controls work, so this is of course just my guess.

**My question is, how to get around it ?** Possibly some easy way.

**The things I tried:**

1- In my UserControl code:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public Size size;
```

..to remove the standard properties from Design-time serialisation.
But (compiler says) I'm only hiding the existing standard property.
Plus it of course doesn't work.
I am still a beginner in c# & .NET so maybe I'm just doing it wrong ?

2- I think I can subscribe to each new control's (on)Load event, let it fully deserialize, and then set what I need. But it seems very cumbersome in code, the properties will needlessly get set twice (or more) etc.
Basically I don't believe there isn't more elegant solution :)

Will be glad for any advices

Comment: You are falling into a standard .NET trap that every programmer falls into sooner or later.  Your "size" property returns a *copy* of the value.  Because Size is a value type.  Assigning the Width property only updates that copy.  Pay more attention to Glenn's answer, he showed the proper way to set it.

Comment: @Hans Passant & Glenn Cuevas:
You both are indeed right. Size type is a struct and its value cant be changed the way I put it in my example above.  
--
As I wrote though, my example was ment just as explanation and didn't show my real code. Which I see is not a good approach (noted for next time :).
I have edited the OP example to make sense.  
--
My question still stands though, since the problem is still there, if I assign the control's properties the right way (in new Example). I.e. the property value I set woun't stick.

Comment: Well, you found out that it is always a *really* bad idea to post fake code in an SO question.  Post real code.

Comment: You are right. Done.--
(Apologies, and thanks for patience. This is my 1st time on stackoverflow so Im trying best way to explain things.)

Comment: Generaly Can you tell me if my assumption about the object deserialisation is right ?

Answer (score 2):

Updated Answer:

Based on your new code:

```
newFrame.Width = 50;
newFrame.Height = 50;
```

Change that to:

```
newFrame.Size = new Size(50, 50);
```

You'll notice that pattern is being used for Location as well.

Original Answer:

When changing the size of a control you have to d a new Size variable, since it's a value type.

Your code should be:

```
newMyUserControl1.size = new Size(50, newMyUserControl1.size.Height);
```

Check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size.aspx

Comment: My example in OP is just an example explaining my approach in a nut, not my exact code.  In any case if you look at it, you'll see I'm not assigning Size (struct), just size.Width, an int. So if I didn't miss anything, my example is actually right ?  Anyway I'm afraid your answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you have a public member called size that is of type Size. If you look at the link I gave you it has this paragraph: "Because the Size class is a value type, it is returned by value, meaning accessing the property returns a copy of the size of the control. So, adjusting the Width or Height properties of the Size returned from this property will not affect the Width or Height of the control. To adjust the Width or Height of the control, you must set the control's Width or Height property, or set the Size property with a new Size."

Comment: Sorry I was tired yesterday and missed your point.
You are indeed right. Size type is a struct and its value cant be changed the way I put it in my example above.  
--
As I wrote though, my example was ment just as explanation and didn't show my real code. Which I see is not a good approach (noted for next time :).
I have edited the OP example to make sense.  
--
My question still stands though, since the problem is still there, if I assign the control's properties the right way. I.e. the property value I set woun't stick.